# Lyx - change margins for one page or one paragraph

Tags: lyx, margins

Is it possible in LYX to change the margins for one page or one paragraph only ? I am trying to insert logos that need to be closer to the sides of page. 
Thanks !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This may or may not be suitable for your specific case. If it misses the mark, please describe in more detail what you want to achieve.

1. Document --> Settings --> LaTeX Preamble, add

   ```
   \usepackage{changepage}
   ```
2. Where you want the narrower margins to start, add an ERT with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, and write

   ```
   \begin{adjustwidth*}{-2cm}{-2cm}
   ```

   in it. The first length extends the inside margin, the second extends the outside margin. If you use the unstarred version, i.e. `\begin{adjustwidth}{-2cm}{-2cm}`, they are the left and right margins, respectively.
3. Step outside the ERT, add the logos, and whatever else should be there. In the screenshot below, I added the first image, then Insert --> Formatting --> Horizontal space --> Horizontal fill, then the second image.
4. Close the environment with a new ERT, containing

   ```
   \end{adjustwidth*}
   ```

[image]